# Can there be a better word for commonplace observations?

Tags: word-choice

On Facebook, one will find numerous pages like "I hate it when people leave my room and leave the door open" or "When a teacher points at me I look back only to find that it is ME".

Can there be a good word to reflect this broad category. I was thinking of Daily happenings, Common observations but I can't find a pleasant to sound word or phrase to represent them.

Comment: Formerly, the word _trivia_ would have fitted, but that has changed its meaning somewhat in the last few decades.

Comment: I'm thinking "rubbish" or "trash" would work, but if you want to get fancy you might call these "mundane" or "quotidian" observations.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Among words for "commonplace observations", *[commonplace](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/commonplace)* itself  (or its plural, *commonplaces*) can be used as a noun with that meaning.  Wiktionary defines noun *commonplace* as "A platitude or cliché" or "Something that is ordinary".  Synonyms for adjective *commonplace* include [hackneyed](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Wikisaurus%3ahackneyed), which is related to words like *banal, bromidic, clichéd, shopworn, stock, threadbare, timeworn, tired, trite, unoriginal,* and *well-worn*, which may suggest nouns like *[banalities](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/banalities)*, *[bromides](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/bromides)*, *[clichés](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/clich%C3%A9s)*.

A *[banality](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/banality)* is something "common in a boring way, to the point of being predictable; containing nothing new or fresh."  A *[bromide](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/bromide)* is "A dose of bromide taken as a sedative", or "A dull person with conventional thoughts [eg] My adviser at college was a bromide who had not had an original thought in years", or "A platitude."  Earlier suggestions related to these terms include adjectives *[mundane](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/mundane)* ("ordinary; not new" or "tedious; repetitive and boring") and *[quotidian](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/quotidian)* ("Having the characteristics of something which can be seen, experienced etc. every day or very commonly; commonplace, ordinary; trivial, mundane").  While quotidian is much more frequently seen as an adjective than as a noun, as a noun it means "(usually with definite article) Commonplace or mundane things regarded as a class".  One might say: "The Facebook postings in question concentrate horribly on the quotidian and are vapid, mundane, commonplace banalities."

Answer (score 2):

How about *platitudes* or *truisms*?

Comment: I don't think either of the OP's examples match those words.